# Removing a row from a custom QAbstractItemModel tree model

Tags: c++, qt

I am facing weird crashes using a simple customized `QAbstractItemModel` and when removing rows from it.

### Model

Assume the following simple `QAbstractItemModel`-based tree:

```
#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>

class UnitsModel:
    public QAbstractItemModel {

    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        UnitsModel(QObject *parent):
            QAbstractItemModel(parent) {

            dimensions.append(qMakePair(
                QString("Length"),
                QStringList() << "Meter" << "Kilometer"));

            dimensions.append(qMakePair(
                QString("Weight"),
                QStringList() << "Gram" << "Kilogram" << "Ton"));
        }


        QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const {
            if (column >= 1)
                return QModelIndex();

            if (!parent.isValid()) {
                /* Index to dimension */
                if (row < dimensions.count())
                    return createIndex(row, column, static_cast<quintptr>(-1));
            }
            else if (parent.row() < dimensions.count()) {
                /* Index to unit */
                const QStringList &units = dimensions.at(parent.row()).second;
                if (row < units.count())
                    return createIndex(row, column, static_cast<quintptr>(parent.row()));
            }

            return QModelIndex();
        }

        QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const {
            if (!child.isValid())
                return QModelIndex();

            const int i = static_cast<qintptr>(child.internalId());
            if (i < 0) {
                /* Child is index to dimension */
                return QModelIndex();
            }
            else {
                /* Child is index to unit */
                if (i < dimensions.count())
                    return createIndex(i, 0, static_cast<quintptr>(-1));
            }

            return QModelIndex();
        }

        int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
            if (!parent.isValid())
                return dimensions.count();

            const int i = static_cast<qintptr>(parent.internalId());
            if (i < 0) {
                /* Index to dimension */
                if (parent.row() < dimensions.count()) {
                    const QStringList &units = dimensions.at(parent.row()).second;
                    return units.count();
                }
            }
            else {
                /* Index to unit */
                return 0;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
            Q_UNUSED(parent);
            return 1;
        }

        QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
            if (!index.isValid())
                return QVariant();

            const QModelIndex parent = index.parent();
            if (!parent.isValid()) {
                if (index.row() >= dimensions.count())
                    return QVariant();

                /* Index to dimension */
                if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
                    return dimensions.at(index.row()).first;
            }
            else {
                /* Index to unit */
                const QStringList &units = dimensions.at(parent.row()).second;
                if (index.row() >= units.count())
                    return QVariant();

                if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
                    return units.at(index.row());
            }

            return QVariant();
        }



        void removeFirstRow() {
            beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0);
            dimensions.removeAt(0);
            endRemoveRows();
        }


    private:
        QList< QPair<QString, QStringList> > dimensions;
};
```

This model can be instantiated and given to a `QTreeView`, where it will display two top level items called *Length* and *Weight*, each containing some child items:
[image: Tree model in <code>QTreeView</code>]

### Issues

Now when I select the shown item *Kilogram* and then call `UnitsMode::removeFirstRow()` the first top level item, *Length*, is properly removed. However, **the selection is lost**.

Even worse, when calling `UnitsModel::removeFirstRow()` again it generates this warning on the terminal:

```
QAbstractItemModel::endRemoveRows:  Invalid index ( 0 , 0 ) in model UnitsModel(0xb46c70)
```

Even worse, if I restart and select *Kilogram* and then call `UnitsModel::removeFirstRow()` twice to remove both the top level items, the tree view is properly cleared (including the above mentioned warning). When then deleting the model while still in use by the `QTreeView` the application **crashes upon exit**. The backtrace traces back to a `QPersistentModelIndex` d-tor, so I suppose the mentioned warning is about a persistent index that could not be adjusted when the rows were removed. When then exiting the application this model index' d-tor tries to deregister itself from the already destroyed model.

I think the main issue is indicated by the warning. What is wrong with the model and why doesn't it correctly adjust the persistent indices?

As a side note: It is perfectly fine to delete the model while still in use as the `QTreeView` is connected to its model's `destroyed()` signal and resets itself with an empty placeholder model.